# How to merge different arrays in a while loop of feof() while using a CSV file?

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I am retrieving data from a CSV file and I want to merge all different arrays in one array so that I can perform a sort on it. My array comes like this:

```
Array ( [0] => kim [1] => abc [2] => xyz ) 
Array ( [0] => roger [1] => def [2] => ghi )
...
```

There are more arrays like this and I want to merge all of them in one array and sort it. Currently my code is the following:

```
<?php
$file = fopen("file.csv","r");
while(! feof($file))
{
  $array= fgetcsv($file);
  print_r($array);
  echo "<br/>";
}

fclose($file);
?>
```

Please help. Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you try something like this :

```
<?php
$file = fopen("file.csv","r");

$array = [];
while(! feof($file))
{
  $array = array_merge($array, fgetcsv($file));
}

sort($array);
print_r($array);

fclose($file);
?>
```